# How to solve complex matrix equations in Go using mat64

Tags: matrix, go, methods

I'm doing matrix math in Go using mat64.  I have a matrix equation I want to solve, something like: (a * b + c) / (d - e) where a, b, c, d, and e are all matrices with real numbers as elements.

mat64 implements matrix math functions as methods.  So, if you wanted to multiply matrix a by b, you'd do something like:

```
// Multiply a by b:
new := mat64.NewDense(x, y, nil)
new.Mul(a, b)
```

However, this method becomes unwieldy when you're looking at more complex equations with a whole bunch of steps such as my example above.

So, is there any way to invoke these routines (or methods in Go in general) without using receivers, forcing me to create a boatload of temporary matrices in order to solve a more complex equation, or am I stuck doing this the ugly way?

Comment: Could you possibly use [ivy](http://godoc.org/robpike.io/ivy)? [(see video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXoG0WX0r_E)

Comment: I hadn't heard of ivy, so I'm glad you let me know about it, thanks.  However,  I think I'd probably be better off with the "ugly way" than going with ivy, if for no other reason than it's probably easier for someone else to come up to speed on and maintain the code going forward.